# Usage of autorelease and retain

Tags: ios5, memory-management, retain, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I have a simple question. Does autorelease work when the retain count is high?

for example... If I am in a view controller and do the following:

```
[self retain];
[self retain];
[self retain];
[self retain];
[self autorelease];
```

If I pop the view, will it be released?

Thanks.

Comment: Autorelease is just a 'deferred release'; it ammounts to release being called at some later, unspecified time. So it would balance only ONE retain.

Comment: In any case, autorelease is **not** a magical method that will delete your object no matter what; retain counts must be balanced. Or better: object ownership mist be made clear and managed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autorelease simply adds the object to an autorelease pool.  When the autorelease pool is deallocated a release message is sent to the object, and all the other objects in that pool.  If your retain count is still greater than zero and you do no further releases, then you will have a memory leak.

I believe that if you do as you say above you will have a retain count of 5 (one from the alloc, and the 4 from the four retains you have above).  You added the object to the autorelease queue so later it will receive a release and reduce the retain count by one.  Finally popping the view should reduce it by one more.  That would leave a retain count of 3.  So I would think that you would have a memory leak.

However if you are using iOS 5, the latest compiler uses ARC (automatic reference counting) and you don't need to worry about this problem.  Well for the most part.

EDITED:  Corrected when objects are sent a release from the autorelease pool.  See:
[Advanced Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)  Sorry for the wrong information.

Comment: It's not "after a certain amount of time". It's when someone calls `drain` or `release` on the autorelease pool, usually the same function that created it, somewhere up the call stack.

Comment: The docs say (or used to say, at least) something along the lines of  'some time later'. For the default pool, I believe it is at the end of each 'cycle' of the run loop. In any case, the object added should still be around at least until the current method/function returns.

Comment: So basically it _is_ a 'delayed release', unless you have a custom pool right there and drain it right away, I guess.

Comment: @ranReloaded I remember an autoreleased object was only around for a short time.  It's intent was to give you just enough time to use it for something and then it was gone.  You could always create another autorelease pool and you could drain any of them whenever you wanted.  But I couldn't seem to find in the documentation anymore where it removed objects on a timely basis.  So I figure I either remember incorrectly or with ARC the autorelease works differently.

Comment: You are right. How short a 'short time' is, obviously depends on the situation. Taking ownership and releasing it when you are done is the wise course of action, I believe.

Comment: My point is that you know *exactly* when the pool will be drained. If you have a pool in your method then it will be drained there. If you create a new thread, you are supposed to manually put autorelease pools in each iteration of the run loop, and around the body of method of the thread; so you know that it happens there. For the main thread (that is the only "built-in" one), it happens at the end of every iteration of the run loop. And there is by convention a pool around the entire application's main function, which you also control.